# JSON - How to interchange values by comparing each other of particular keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, key, data-interchange

I am having JSON data this way with  key:reportData and array of values,

```
 {"reportData":[
    ["1185","R","4t","G","06","L","GT","04309","2546","2015","CF FE","01H1","20","23840","FF20"],
    ["1186","R","5t","R","01","L","TP","00110","1854","2016","FE LL","06W3","01","19065","FB01"],
    ["1187","R","6t","H","06","L","TP","04333","1864","2015","CF FE SL","0209","FD22","19845",null],
    ["1188","R","7t","H","06","L","PR","04041","6951","2015","CC CT FE GN PC","0070","00","36590","LB00"],
    ["1189","R","8t","H","06","L","WS","04290","4450","2014","CF   EN   FE   PC   TP","0070","EA30","28320.00",null],
    ["1190","R","9t","H","06","L","LA","04915","4430","2015","CF DK FE RR TC","0040","10","23680","FB10"],
    ["1191","R","10t","H","06","L","LF","04335","2532","2015","CF FE GE","0040","FC10","22970",null],
    ["1192","R","11t","H","06","L","SA","04772","8345","2015","BZ C8 FE","01D6","13","33390","LC13"]]}
```

I want to compare and interchange data in each array element :  particularly 12th and 14th indexes.

```
ex: in "reportData":[
    ["1185","R","4t","G","06","L","GT","04309","2546","2015","CF FE","01H1","20","23840","FF20"]]
```

ie, I want to compare and interchange '20' with 'FF20' using this logic .

```
If 14th index value != null then assign,

   12th index=14th index value.

else if 14th index value ==null,

then leave 12th index=12th index value as it is.
```

And this has to be repeated for all the list of arrays in the "reportData" key.

So, my final JSON would be this way,

```
    "reportData":[
["1185","R","4t","G","06","L","GT","04309","2546","2015","CF FE","01H1","FF20","23840","FF20"],//interchange 12th with 14th as 14th !=null
["1186","R","5t","R","01","L","TP","00110","1854","2016","FE LL","06W3","FB01","19065","FB01"],//interchange 12th with 14th as 14th !=null
["1187","R","6t","H","06","L","TP","04333","1864","2015","CF FE SL","0209","FD22","19845",null],//leave 12th as IT IS as 14th ==null
["1188","R","7t","H","06","L","PR","04041","6951","2015","CC CT FE GN PC","0070","00","36590","LB00"],//interchange 12th with 14th as 14th !=null
["1189","R","8t","H","06","L","WS","04290","4450","2014","CF   EN   FE   PC   TP","0070","EA30","28320.00",null],//leave 12th as IT IS as 14th ==null
["1190","R","9t","H","06","L","LA","04915","4430","2015","CF DK FE RR TC","0040","10","23680","FB10"],//interchange 12th with 14th as 14th !=null
["1191","R","10t","H","06","L","LF","04335","2532","2015","CF FE GE","0040","FC10","22970",null],//leave 12th as IT IS as 14th ==null
["1192","R","11t","H","06","L","SA","04772","8345","2015","BZ C8 FE","01D6","13","33390","LC13"]]//interchange 12th with 14th as 14th !=null
```

I tried this way but it is interchanging ,

```
function swapJsonKeyValues(input) {
        var one=['FCOL,ICOL']; output = {};
        for (one in input) {
            if (input.hasOwnProperty(one)) {
                output[input[one]] = one;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: OP, what's the relevance of `FCOL` and `ICOL` in your example?

Comment: Did you try any of the answers, and did they work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the array with `FCOL` and `ICOL` are for in your example function, but here's one way you might approach this problem.

I've called the function `copyElement` because `swapJsonKeyValues` doesn't work. 1) Assuming you've already parsed the data it's now a JS object, not JSON 2) you're not swapping key/value pairs, you're simply copying an element based on a condition.

All the function does is check that the each array is at least 14 elements long, and if it is checks to see if the 14th element isn't `null`. If it is copy the value to element 12. `map` simply returns a new array after the callback has been run on each array in `reportData`.

```
function copyElement(obj) {
  return obj.reportData.map(function (el) {
     if (el.length >= 14 && el[14] !== null) el[12] = el[14];
     return el;
  });
}

copyElement(obj);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ydmppkqm/)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose data = the json object, then

```
data.reportData.forEach(function(row){
    if(row[14] != null)
        row[12] = row[14];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
var jsonData =  {"reportData":[
    ["1185","R","4t","G","06","L","GT","04309","2546","2015","CF FE","01H1","20","23840","FF20"],
    ["1186","R","5t","R","01","L","TP","00110","1854","2016","FE LL","06W3","01","19065","FB01"],
    ["1187","R","6t","H","06","L","TP","04333","1864","2015","CF FE SL","0209","FD22","19845",null],
    ["1188","R","7t","H","06","L","PR","04041","6951","2015","CC CT FE GN PC","0070","00","36590","LB00"],
    ["1189","R","8t","H","06","L","WS","04290","4450","2014","CF   EN   FE   PC   TP","0070","EA30","28320.00",null],
    ["1190","R","9t","H","06","L","LA","04915","4430","2015","CF DK FE RR TC","0040","10","23680","FB10"],
    ["1191","R","10t","H","06","L","LF","04335","2532","2015","CF FE GE","0040","FC10","22970",null],
    ["1192","R","11t","H","06","L","SA","04772","8345","2015","BZ C8 FE","01D6","13","33390","LC13"]]}

jsonData.reportData.map(function (row) {return row[12] = (row[14]) ? row[14] : row[12];})
console.log(jsonData);
```

The map callback function will check those conditions and will return the desired data.